# Move record to different table MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I see this question have been asked in many different ways, but I don't understand them quite well.

I want to move my records that have expired (their date is behind/smaller than `now()` - each one has a field with their date in, this is in seconds from 1970) to a different identical table. This is to make the event-cue smaller in the main table.

Is there any single query I can use to move a record to a different table? I can do the checking of the time/when expires myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cant do this in one query, you have to perform two:
query 1:

```
INSERT INTO newtable SELECT * FROM oldtable WHERE date<now();
```

query 2:

```
DELETE FROM oldtable WHERE date <= SELECT MAX(date) FROM newtable
```

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into backupTable (select field1, field2 from mainTable where myDate < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()))

delete from mainTable where myDate < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())
```

Comment: Everything would be ok if queries would run in same second, which in larger tables is less possible. In your case you could delete more rows than you moved.